# Django how to add query results foreign key model to queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How can I get the `Author` model objects into a queryset through the foreign key of `B` model? I would like to use the `Author` objects in my template.

```
#Models.py
    
class Book(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class Author(models.Model):
    # lots of fields

class B(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)

selected_book = "ABC"
book = Book.objects.get(name=selected_book)
original_queryset = B.objects.filter(name=book)

for i in original_queryset:
    print(i.author) # returns what i want
    queryset = # get all i.author objects somehow

return render(request,"template.html", {"queryset": queryset}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `for` loop. then add the following line after the `original_queryset = B.objects.filter(name=book)` line->

`queryset = original_queryset.author`

If this doesn't work then let me know. I hope  I can help you.

You can rename your `B` model's `author` field to `authors`, that makes your code more meaningful because `ForeignKey` field can store many data. In your code, you have made your `B` model's `author` field as a `ForeignKey` field, which means **books** can have multiple **authors**. You can see the django documentation of [ForeignKey reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).
If you change as I told you then don't forget to **run migration**(`python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` command in your cmd) and change the line `queryset = original_queryset.author` to `queryset = original_queryset.authors`

#### Another approach

You can pass the `original_queryset` in the `context` of the template,(i.e: `{'queryset':original_queryset }`) then in your `template.html`, you can add tages like this:

```
{% for book in queryset %}
<ul>
{% for author in book.author %}
<li>author.name</li>
....
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

By doing these, you can place your books and authors in your template nicely. If it still shows error, message me, I hope I can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help Omayer, the result from print(original_queryset) returns a dict. <QuerySet [<B: B object (3)>]>, so that's why I was using the for loop. As such doing what you suggested returns the error "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'author'"

Comment: The issue was I was trying to make the queryset a dict rather I thought I had tried but I just needed to make it a list for it to work.

Comment: @Nick I have edited my answer, in the **Another approach**, if you follow the steps, then I hope no error will be found.